# jQuery keyboard arrow navigation not working on autocomplete dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an autocomplete list populated via an ajax call, which makes a call to the API each time a key is pressed in the textbox.

This works fine, and the list is displayed with the desired results. The problem is, I want to add keyboard navigation with the up/down arrow keys and scroll through the list items, changing the class to "selected" for the current item.

The code to scroll through the list works on its own, but stops working in conjunction with the ajax call. I'm assuming there must be some kind of conflict going on which resets something each time the ajax call is made, stopping the index values of the list items from being properly recognised? is this code correct?

THE HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="textBox" autocomplete="off" />
       <ul id="predictiveList">
          <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="test">test2</a></li>
          <li><a href="test">test3</a></li>
        </ul>              
 </form>
```

THE JQUERY

```
var $listItems = $('#predictiveList li');

$('#textBox').live('keyup', function(e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode,
    $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
    $current;

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if ( key == 40 ) // Down key
    {
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.next();
        }
    }
    else if ( key == 38 ) // Up key
    {
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
        }
    }

     $current.addClass('selected') ;
});


$('#textBox').live('keyup', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        url: 'http://www.apiCallurlhere.js?callback=displayOptions'
    });
});


/******** Generates dropdown from results of AJAX call ***********/

function displayOptions(data){ 

    $('#predictiveList').show();  
    var obj = data.results;
    var dropdownOptions = '';

    //generate list of options for dropdown menu
    $.each( obj, function( i, v ) {
        dropdownOptions += '<li><a href="' + v.pubId + '">' + v.place + '</a></li>';

    });
    $('#predictiveList').html(dropdownOptions); 

}
```

as I said, both work fine independently, but when the AJAX call is included in the page at the same time as the keyboard nav, the arrow navigation stops working (though the list still shows up and populates as expected)

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: tried this but $selected.length always returs 0 and its not entering in else condition

Answer (score 0):

Ah, do not use keyup event to fetch the autocomplete list.

When you press up or down arrows, it calls the ajax to refresh the list, and probably ".selected" class is getting removed.

So instead, use change event:

```
$('#textBox').live('change', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        url: 'http://www.apiCallurlhere.js?callback=displayOptions'
    });
});
```

However, .live() method is deprecated in 1.7 and REMOVED in 1.9. So you really should use .on() method instead:

```
$(document).on('change', '#textBox', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        url: 'http://www.apiCallurlhere.js?callback=displayOptions'
    });
});
```

Try my first solution with .live() method first. If it works, then try my second solution to avoid using deprecated .live() method.